# Migrating JAX-WS RI to Spring controlled service without SOAP?

Tags: spring, soap, jax-ws

Excuse me if I use incorrect terminology, I'm a bit new to this.  I've created a web service using Sun's JAX-WS RI "Provider" implementation.  We send this service plain XML, and it responds in plain XML.  I've tried to move this into Spring so the services are accessible via Spring context, but now it's looking for a SOAP envelope, which we are not using. How do I tell it I am not using SOAP?

My web.xml looks like this:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <display-name>MyServiceImpl</display-name>
    <servlet-name>MyServiceImpl</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSSpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServiceImpl</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myServiceUrl</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And here's my applicationContext.xml:

```
<!-- this bean implements web service methods -->
<bean id="myService" class="com.acme.MyServiceImpl" />

<bean class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.SpringBinding">
    <property name="url" value="/myServiceUrl" />
    <property name="service">
        <bean class="org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService">
            <property name="bean">
                <ref local="myService" />
            </property>
            <property name="impl" value="com.acme.MyServiceImpl" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

My service class looks something like this:

```
@javax.xml.ws.WebServiceProvider
@javax.xml.ws.ServiceMode(value=javax.xml.ws.Service.Mode.MESSAGE)
public class MyServiceImpl implements Provider<Source> {

@Override
public Source invoke(Source source) {
... // unmarshal the source object using JAXB, do work, marshall a response back
}
```

The error message I receive upon sending the service my basic XML is:

> `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><faultcode>S:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: unexpected XML tag. expected: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope but found: {}Request</faultstring></S:Fault></S:Body></S:Envelope>`

How do I rid the SOAP?

Answer (score 0):

Found it; need to specify the bindingId (which was defined in the sun-jaxws.xml previously) on the web service bean:

```
<property name="service">
    <bean class="org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService">
        <property name="bean">
            <ref local="myService" />
        </property>
        <property name="impl" value="com.acme.MyServiceImpl" />
        <property name="bindingID" value="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/http" />
    </bean>
</property>
```